# How to require many Lua strcip in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, lua

I have a problem when i require lua in xcode

there are two strcips:

in bar.lua:

```
bar =function()
    print("bar")
end
```

in foo.lua:

```
require "bar"
bar()
```

in xcode i write this code:

```
NSString * tagsString = @"bar,foo";
NSArray * tagsArray = [tagsString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
for (NSString* luaFileName in tagsArray) {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:luaFileName ofType:@"lua"];
    if (luaL_loadfile(_L, [path UTF8String])!=0){
        NSLog(@"luaL_loadfile error:%s",lua_tostring(_L, -1));
    }
    if (lua_pcall(_L, 0, 0, 0)!=0){
        NSLog(@"lua_pcall error？:%s",lua_tostring(_L, -1));
    }
}
```

but it doesnot work:

```
lua_pcall error？:...on/2DD58CF6-044C-405C-885F-46B98BF6F355/0317.app/foo.lua:6: module 'bar' not found:
no field package.preload['bar']
no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.3/bar.lua'
no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.3/bar/init.lua'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/bar.lua'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/bar/init.lua'
no file './bar.lua'
no file './bar/init.lua'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/bar.so'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/loadall.so'
no file './bar.so'
```

I'm pretty sure that ./bar.lua is exist

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your current working directory is not the one where app is resided, so lua can't find bar.lua, even if it's in same dir as foo.lua.

Lua will search few locations, some of them searched by absolute path, like '/usr/local/share/...', others searched by relative path.

`./bar.lua` is searched by relative path, so actual working directory now matters.

Comment: i sloved this problem :NSString *appPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
    [self runLuaCode:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"appPath = '%@/?.lua'",appPath]];

Answer (score 0):

i sloved this problem by this code:
NSString *appPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]; [self runLuaCode:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"appPath = '%@/?.lua'",appPath]];